# Trouble making a heart symbol in Lua?

Tags: lua, ascii

I was wondering how to make the heart sign or `"♥"` in Lua, I have tried `\003` because that is the ASCII code for it, but it does not print it out.

Comment: `\003` is not the ASCII code for the heart sign. Its Unicode code point is U+2665, and its HTML code is `&#x2665;` or `&#9829;`.

Comment: So, how would i return that in lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has little to do with Lua.

You need to find out which character set and encoding is used in your environment and select a font that supports ♥ in that encoding.

Then you need to use an editor for your Lua script that saves in that encoding. If that part is not possible then you can determine the byte sequence required, code it as numeric escapes in a literal string and save in a compatible encoding such as CP437. For example, if you are outputting to a UTF-8 processor, "\xE2\x99\xA5".

Keep in mind that a Lua string is a counted sequence of bytes. It's up to you and your editor to put the right bytes in in the file, it's up to your environment (e.g., console) to interpret those bytes in a particular character encoding, and up to the font to display the glyph.

In a Windows console, you can select the Lucinda Console font, `chcp 65001` to use UTF-8 and use Lua 5.1 like this: `lua -e "print('\226\153\165')"`. As a comparison, `chcp 437` to use IBM437 and use Lua 5.1 like this: `lua -e "print('\003')"`.

Answer (score 2):

For ASCII, only range `0x20` to `0x7E` are printable. Others, including `0x03`, isn't printable. Printing its value would be up to the implementation.

If the environment supports Unicode, you can simply call:

```
print("♥")
```

For instance, [Lua Demo](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo) outputs `♥`, same in [ideone](http://ideone.com/GBmk4T).

Comment: Yes, but in a .lua file all that shows up as is a ? and prints as a ?

Comment: Then probably Unicode isn't supported in your environment.

Comment: Lua is charset agnostic (for the most part). If your console and your souce-code agree on the charset, you get good output.

Comment: Actually `print("\003")` works on my machine, but again, it's implementation-defined.

Comment: @Alexwall that is probably an issue on the *editor* you are using to write Lua.